# Selecting text from each LI in a UL

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Having trouble selecting and and collecting the text from each of the LI in a UL. Please see what I have so far for an example, http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/YYbfY/

HTML

```
<div data-role="navbar" data-mini="true">
    <ul id="resultHeader">
        <li><span class='ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-up-b'><span class='ui-btn-inner'>Column A</span></span></li>
        <li><span class='ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-up-b'><span class='ui-btn-inner'>Column B</span></span></li>
        <li><span class='ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-up-b'><span class='ui-btn-inner'>Column C</span></span></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class='resultRow'>
        <li><span class='ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-up-d' title='mack5.com.'><span class='ui-btn-inner'>Item 1</span></span></li>
        <li><span class='ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-up-d'><span class='ui-btn-inner'>Item 2</span></span></li>
        <li><span class='ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-up-d'><span class='ui-btn-inner'>Item 3</span></span></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class='resultRow'>
        <li><span class='ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-up-d' title='mack5.com.'><span class='ui-btn-inner'>Item 1</span></span></li>
        <li><span class='ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-up-d'><span class='ui-btn-inner'>Item 2</span></span></li>
        <li><span class='ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-up-d'><span class='ui-btn-inner'>Item 3</span></span></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class='resultRow'>
        <li><span class='ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-up-d' title='mack5.com.'><span class='ui-btn-inner'>Item 1</span></span></li>
        <li><span class='ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-up-d'><span class='ui-btn-inner'>Item 2</span></span></li>
        <li><span class='ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-btn-up-d'><span class='ui-btn-inner'>Item 3</span></span></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<textarea id="clipText-cell"></textarea>
<textarea id="clipText-row"></textarea>
<textarea id="clipText-all"></textarea>

<div id="copyPopup" data-role="popup" data-positionTo="origin">
    <div data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true">
        <a href="" data-role="button" id="copyCell-btn">Copy '<span id="copyCellBtn-text"></span>'</a>
        <a href="" data-role="button" id="copyRow-btn">Copy Row</a>
        <a href="" data-role="button" id=copyAll-btn>Copy All Rows</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
var tapTimer, isTapHold = false;
$(".resultRow li").bind("vmousedown vmouseup", function(e) {
    var clickedLi = $(this).parent().parent("li");
    var clickedUl = clickedLi.parent("ul");
    var cellText = $(this).text();
    var rowText = "";
    var tableText = "";    
    var rows = [];
    var table = [];

    if (e.type == "vmousedown") {
        tapTimer = setTimeout(function() {
            isTapHold = true;
            //alert("Click-Hold for 1.5 seconds.");
            $("#copyCellBtn-text").html(cellText);
            $("#clipText-cell").val(cellText);
            $("#clipText-row").val(rowText);
            $("#clipText-all").val(tableText);            
            $("#copyPopup").popup("open", {
                x: (e.pageX + 100),
                y: (e.pageY + 60)
            });
        }, 1500);
    } else {
        // e.type = 'vmouseup'
        // Clear the timeout if not already reached
        clearTimeout(tapTimer);

        // if flag is set to false, regular tap or click
        if (!isTapHold) {
            // Not Click-Hold, do nothing
        }

        // Reset flag
        isTapHold = false;
    }
});
```

What I want to have happen is when a user click-holds or tap-holds, a popup menu appears where they can choose to Copy the text in they clicked on, the text from entire row, or the text from the entire table.

To collect the row data, I am trying trying to figure out how to iterate over each `li` in the `ul` that was clicked, and collect all the text in the corresponding `textarea`. Once I can get this, I can create a loop to do the same thing to all the `ul`'s to collect all the text later.

Comment: Twisty, I don't see a table/rows in the HTML.

Comment: You are binding your event handler to the li elements, but then within the handler you try to say `clickedLi = $(this).parent().parent("li");` - that won't return any elements, because `this` is the clicked li and its parent's parent is a div. Perhaps you intended to bind the event to `"span.ui-btn-inner"`?

Comment: @nnnnnn In the context of a ListView, I wanted to bind to the `li` cause in future cases, the `span` may not be there. What if the `li` contained just a link, a div, or just text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twisty, I think I have managed to penetrate table/rows.

You might like to consider organising the code along the following lines :

```
$(function() {
    var $$ = {};//cache of static jQuery objects
    $$.copyCellBtn_text = $("#copyCellBtn-text");
    $$.clipText_cell = $("#clipText-cell");
    $$.clipText_row = $("#clipText-row");
    $$.clipText_all = $("#clipText-all");
    $$.copyPopup = $("#copyPopup");

    var tapTimer, 
        isTapHold = false, 
        tapHoldDelay = 1500,
        textJoinStr = ', ',//adjust as required
        textObj = { //fully populated later
            cell: '',
            row: '',
            table: ''
        };

    function makeTapTimer(e) {
        return setTimeout(function() {
            isTapHold = true;
            //alert("Click-Hold for 1.5 seconds.");
            $$.copyCellBtn_text.html(textObj.cell);
            $$.clipText_cell.val(textObj.cell);
            $$.clipText_row.val(textObj.row);
            $$.clipText_all.val(textObj.table);
            $$.copyPopup.popup("open", {
                x: (e.pageX + 100),
                y: (e.pageY + 60)
            });
        }, tapHoldDelay);
    }

    $("#resultHeader").closest("div").on("vmousedown", ".resultRow li", function(e) {
        tapTimer = makeTapTimer(e);

        var clickedCell = $(this);//==button
        var clickedUl = clickedCell.closest("ul");//==row
        var clickedTable = clickedCell.closest("div");//==table

        textObj.cell = clickedCell.text();

        textObj.row = clickedUl.data('text');
        if(!textObj.row) {
            textObj.row = $.map(clickedUl.find("li"), function(btn, i) {
                return $(btn).text();
            }).join(textJoinStr);
            clickedUl.data('text', textObj.row);
        }

        textObj.table = clickedTable.data('text');
        if(!textObj.table) {
            textObj.table = $.map(clickedTable.find(".resultRow li"), function(btn, i) {
                return $(btn).text();
            }).join(textJoinStr);
            clickedTable.data('text', textObj.table);
        }
    }).on('vmouseup', function() {
        clearTimeout(tapTimer);
        isTapHold = false;
    });
});
```

*untested - may need debugging*

Comment: Elegant Object Oriented solution. I will test it and see how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: Minor clean up, you attempted to define `textObject` as a new variable 3 times (Line 39, Line 41, and Line 49). Still testing.

Comment: Tested, and I will use this after some modifications: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/YYbfY/29/

Comment: Well done, you spotted - ummm - deliberate mistake - not passing the mousedown event through to `tapHoldAction()`. Fixed above.

Comment: I see what you did, will test it. The Popup wasn't getting passed the event object and thus got no x, y values and was not loading upon the click-hold. Is `tapTimer = setTimeout(function(){ tapHoldAction(event) }, tapHoldDelay);` not good practice?

Comment: Testy, `setTimeout(function(){...}, ...);` is fine. My approach is slightly showy. I prefer it because the line `tapTimer = makeTapTimer(e);` keeps the main handler clean and tidy. Ultimately, it's just a question of style - there's no definitive solution.

Comment: Who's Testy?? :D Here is my final fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/YYbfY/34/ Everything works there. Still trying to implement it in my production code. Thanks again for the assistance, I like your style.

Comment: TWISTY!! I don't know where Testy came from.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code snippet

```
var rowtext = "" ;
    var rowText = $.each(clickedLi.parent("ul").children("li"),function(){
        rowtext += $(this).find("span.ui-btn-inner").html(); });
```

Check the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/YYbfY/26/

Thanks

Comment: That does work, yet I think I like @Beetroot-Beetroot answer more.